# Use calibration matrix to know CCD sensor size

Tags: computer-vision, calibration

How can we know the camera sensor size from the calibration matrix?

I already have the calibration matrix. But the focal length is in pixels form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "focal length" in the calibration matrix is not actually expressed in pixels. It is in fact a ratio that relates the sensor size in the real world to the size of a pixel in the image. It relates the focal length of the lens to distances in the image using a scaling factor in each dimension. More details in [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Intrinsic_parameters).

Comment: Okay, so how can we get the scaling factor ?

Comment: is the scaling factor same thing as the pixel size of each edge?

Comment: Do you know the focal length in mm? If yes then the scaling factor `m_x = \alpha_x / f_x`.

Comment: all i want to know is how can we get the alpha_x ?

Comment: alpha_x is the first entry in the intrinsic calibration matrix.

Comment: opps....actually this is not what i mean. what i mean is if we have a camera and with the datasheet, is the m_x something equal to each pixel size? what i mean pixel size is (number of pixel)/(sensor size) for one edge.

Comment: m_x is the scaling factor that converts the focal length from the number of meters (f_x) to the number of pixels (alpha_x). This implies that the physical size of every pixel on the sensor is 1/m_x.

Answer (score 1):

As Zaphod says, you can get a decent approximation combining the calibration matrix with a known focal length for the lens in mm.

A more precise method: open the box, read the serial type number of the CCD, look it up on the interwebs. There are only a handful of CCD manufacturers, and they all publish their spec sheets on the web. [Here](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/452200/HAMAMATSU/S9979_11.html) is an example.